# Does EasyUI Catch Elements Only With ID Attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

I have an number input like this:

```
<input class="easyui-numberbox" data-options="precision:2,required:false" id="price3" name="price3" value="" />
```

But I can't get the input value with this:

```
$("input[name=price3]").numberbox('getValue')
```

But I can get the input value with ID attribute of input:

```
$("#price3").numberbox('getValue')
```

Should I define my all inputs an ID attribute to work with EasyUI?

Regards,

Comment: Is there anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can get an element with a specific attribute value as well. In your example try

```
$('input[numberboxname="price3"]').val()
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. But EasyUI doesn't accept this.

Comment: That's odd, I tried with the code you provided and it works. Did you try getting the numberboxname attribute? (although the attribute is called "name", it is changed to "numberboxname" in numberboxes). Which version of jquery-EasyUI are you using?

Comment: I'll check in a few days when I'm back home :) I solved this by "id" tag. You're telling that "name" is changed to "numberboxname".  I'll check this then tell you my friend.